# Reversing void array & what datatype to cast to

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I've allocated memory for an array like this:

```
void *buf;
buf = calloc(8192, 1);
```

Now i read 8192 Byte to the array from file stream of a raw file:

```
uint32_t fpos = 0;
int n;
n = fread(buf,1,8192,file);
fpos += n;
```

I would use a function like:

```
static void reverseBuffer(void *buf){
        for(int a = 0; a < sizeof(buf)>>1; a++){
            uint8_t temp = (uint8_t) buf[a];
            buf[a] = buf[sizeof(buf) - a - 1];
            buf[sizeof(buf) - a - 1] = temp;
        }
}
```

Obviously it doesn't really work, how would i need to cast the array and what datatype would i need to use? I tried casting it to uint_8 since its guaranteed to be of size 1Byte.

cheers

Comment: If it's an array of bytes, why do you type it as a `void*` at all? Just make it a `uint_8*` in the first place. If you need to cast, cast the pointer before attempting to index into it.

Comment: It's not my codebase ;p. You mean like uint_8 temp = (uint8_t*) buf[a]?

Comment: Sorry, meant ((uint_8*) buf)[a]. Seems to work tho, thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` does not what you expect. `buf` is a pointer, so its size is either 4 or 8 depending on if you run this on 32 or 64 bit operating system. Where `buf` points does is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how would I need to cast the array and what data type would I need to use? I tried casting it to `uint_8` since its guaranteed to be of size 1Byte.*

So you are almost there.

It's just that you cannot dereference a `void`-pointer as it's not clear to which type this should evaluate, as it is pointing to `void`.

The solution is to cast the *pointer* to some *specific* pointer type. In your case to `uint8_t*` and only then dereference it.

Also your code assumes `sizeof buf` would give you the size of the array, which it does not. It gives you the size of `buf` and as `buf` is a pointer (`void*`) you get the size of a pointer, which is either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the OS you are running this code on.

So, you *need* make the function aware of the array's size. This can be done by just passing it in.

The function then might look like this:

```
static void reverseBuffer(size_t size, void * buf) {
    for (size_t a = 0; a < size >> 1; a++) {
        uint8_t temp = ((uint8_t*) buf)[a];
        ((uint8_t*) buf)[a] = ((uint8_t*) buf)[size - a - 1];
        ((uint8_t*) buf)[sizeof- a - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

or introduce a local correctly typed variable:

```
static void reverseBuffer(size_t size, void * buf) {
    uint8_t * p = buf;

    for (size_t a = 0; a < size >> 1; a++) {
        uint8_t temp = p[a];
        p[a] = p[size - a - 1];
        p[size - a - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

or already define the function using the correct type:

```
static void reverseBuffer(size_t size, uint8_t * p) {
    for (size_t a = 0; a < size >> 1; a++) {
        uint8_t temp = p[a];
        p[a] = p[size - a - 1];
        p[size - a - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Call it like this

```
  reverseBuffer(8192, buf);
```

Comment: Cheers. Is there a difference in performance between the three approaches? Besides having to declare another variable in the 2nd method. Am i correct that 3rd would be the fastest, since the compiler already knows the type its dealing with?

Comment: @liquid: Any decent compiler would create the more or less same assembler code from all three I suspect. Still, my choice would be be the third, as the function's declaration already tells which type it expected, namely (a pointer to) `uint8_t`. Go for the 3rd.

Comment: Thanks. Currently working with compiler optimization off tho. Nevertheless went with option3 and created functions for 8/16bit since im buffering in 8bit and doing the dsp in 16bit. Gives me the option to reverse the whole block directly after buffering or do it in smaller chunks during the processing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to reverse an array without knowing the types.

Consider what it means to reverse an array. We want to swap the first and last element, the second and second to last element, and so on.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3] => [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

This works because we know the size of each element. In reality, data exists as ones and zeroes.

We can only swap the first and last element if we know how big the first and last element is.

```
// Element size is 3 bits
[000, 001, 010, 100] => [100, 010, 001, 000]
```

Without knowing the size of each element, it is impossible to know where the first element stops and what should be swapped.

```
// Unknown element size
000001010100

// Element size 1
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

// Element size 2
[00, 00, 01, 01, 01, 00] => [00, 01, 01, 01, 00, 00]

// Element size 4
[0000, 0101, 0100] => [0100, 0101, 0000]
```

The types define how many bits form one element (e.g. an int might be 32 bits and a long might be 64 bits).

Without knowing the type it is impossible to know the element size and without knowing the element size it is impossible to reverse the list.

Comment: makes sense, assuming an element has 8bit/1Byte, so uint8_t type. Is there a way to assign new values like buf[index] = x? I can access the array via. ((uint8_t*) buf)[index]. Would i have to cast the array beforehand like uint8_t *temp = (uint8_t*) buf; ?

Comment: "*It is not possible to reverse an array without knowing the types.*" as well if you do not know the array's, which is the case for the OP's code.

Answer (score -1):

In your loop, maybe `sizeof(buf)>>1` instead of `sizeof(buf)>>2` would make your code works.

Comment: You're right that it should be >>2 to divide by 2. But that's not the error. Compiler says that im trying to dereference void*. Also should avoid divide operator "/" since its super inefficient on the platform im using.